# How do you perfectly hash a union of a possibly unicode char with a 32-bit integer?

Tags: algorithm, hash, union, d

I've never really had the need to create hash function before but right now it seems like the best solution for this.

I haven't tried anything, but I guess what I would try first is to hash take the unicode integer as the least significant 32-bits of a long.  Then in the most significant 32-bits, store the integer.

```
struct Symbol
{
private:
   enum Type {
      Terminal,
      Variable,
   }
   union {
      char m_term;
      int m_var;
   }
   Type m_type;

public:
   this(char term) {
      m_type = Type.Terminal;
      m_term = term;
   }

   this(int var) {
      m_type = Type.Variable;
      m_var = var;
   }
}
```

`Symbol` is the struct I'd like to hash.  It contains a union which we should hash to achieve this.  Was just wondering if my approach above is correct.

Comment: let me point out an important fact: a `char` is not a unicode character, it is a UTF-8 code unit. In other words, a single byte that can form a character. You might want to use `dchar`, which can hold any code point (whether this is a "character" needs an essay on unicode to decide but i am guessing it will work for you probably). A `dchar` is a 32 bit value, meaning it will be the same size as that `int`.

Comment: Another fact: a Symbol never has both `m_term` and `m_var`; it has one or the other. So there are never two things to put into a `long`. (Well, there are two things: one is an `enum` which is effectively a single bit, and the other one is a (probably) small value, alrhough its precise type depends on the enum.)

Comment: @rici why not do it my way since those bits will not be used?  I mean I would zero out the other one of course.

Comment: Because it's not going to be a good hash. The possible hash values are not randomly diatributed in the value space.

Comment: @rici I'm alway down for some good hash ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to commenters.

```
   bool opEquals(Symbol sym) const {
      if (m_type == Type.Terminal) 
         return m_term == sym.m_term;
      else
         return m_var == sym.m_var;
   }

   ulong toHash() {
      ulong bit = m_type;
      ulong key;
      if (m_type == Type.Terminal) 
         key = cast(ulong) m_term;
      else
         key = m_var;
      return bit | (key << 1);
   }
```

Comment: That's better, but your `opEquals` should first check that `m_type == sym.m_type` and otherwise return false. Otherwise, you'll end up comparing apples with organges (m_term with m_var) in a way which might accidentally yield a false positive.